# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Installation/Change Fails - "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I am trying to install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, but I am receiving an error each time. I have tried both the web installer and the ISO, and I have also tried going into Control Panel/Programs and modifying the 2015 install. All of these result in the same error: "Setup Engine - The parameter is incorrect". I've read about some of the other issues with the installer, but I'm hoping somebody else might have seen this one or something similar. The logs always have the following error in them:

[1B10:1DA0][2016-07-18T11:39:28]e000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to convert version:  to DWORD64 for ProductCode: {284FA9A0-CEDD-81D3-5A19-5858E95FD0C4}

[1B10:1DA0][2016-07-18T11:39:28]e151: Detect failed for package: Win10_Universal_CRT_SDK_Extension_SDK, error: 0x80070057

I have even tried to download the full installer for VS2015, but all installers seem to run through the same error. Any ideas on how I might repair this particular component so the installs will succeed?

Additional information, this is happening on a VM of Windows 10 running in Parallels 11.

[Screen shot of installer failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3aAH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar issue here： https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/974081/visual-studio-update-3-installation-keeps-failing-error-message-setup-engine-the-parameter-is-incorrect
The reply from Heath[MSFT]:

> The logs confirm that some of your Windows Installer product
>   registration is corrupt. For the first issue, open a command prompt
>   (preferably elevated to avoid multiple UAC prompts later) and run the
>   following:
>
> ```
> start /wait msiexec /fomus {284FA9A0-CEDD-81D3-5A19-5858E95FD0C4} REINSTALL=ALL
> ```
>
> That should get
>   you past the first problem. If it does not, manually remove the
>   product like so and re-install it from the package cache:
>
> ```
> start /wait msiexec /x {284FA9A0-CEDD-81D3-5A19-5858E95FD0C4} IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL 
> start /wait msiexec /i "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A79F6653-6AF1-4AF2-BC15-F5D6C05E1E6A}v2.0.40326.0\packages\sptoolsDependencies\enu\WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi" ADDLOCAL=ALL NOVSUI=1
> ```
>
> (change the above file
>   WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi according to your log file record) After
>   this, installing VS Update 3 should work.

Comment: Thanks very much, those commands let me clean things up and run the installer without issues.  Specifically, the command below removed it and I was able to continue:       `start /wait msiexec /x {284FA9A0-CEDD-81D3-5A19-5858E95FD0C4} IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem which at its root exhibited the same issue identified above in the Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 setup error (I couldn't install SSMS 17.1 which uses the Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell).  I tried the solution above which unfortunately did not work for me.  I did some more digging through the vs_isoshell.exe log file and found lines similar to those below.

```
[6BE0:36E0][2017-07-13T13:05:36]i000: Error 0x80070057: Failed to convert version: to DWORD64 for ProductCode: {9A7E3828-17FB-3E0C-9B28-48493E01937A}
```

The ProductCode refers to the "Microsoft Visual C++ 15 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.10.24269".

A perusal of my installed programs showed I did not have this installed, and I was unable to install it again due to a later version being present (it turns out it was upgraded, or removed, when I installed Visual Studio 2017).

I did some more searching and came across [this page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rALdxh0LOUsJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/844326/cant-run-vs2013-install-after-upgrade-to-win8-1%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) which had steps I adapted to my situation. I performed the same registry profiling of the installer with Process Monitor and the same key was missing.  I added a key called **DisplayVersion** (string - REG_SZ) to the path below with a value of **14.10.24629** and that worked.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\8283E7A9BF71C0E3B9828494E31039A7\InstallProperties]
```

Adding the key/value pair allowed the installation of the VS 2015 Update 3 Isolated Shell to finish successfully which in turn allowed the SSMS 17.1 installation to complete successfully.